# How to force redraw ApexCharts?

Tags: apexcharts

I'm updating ApexCharts using `updateSeries` while the chart is hidden using `display: none`. When the series is being updated I think it is checking the width of the element that it is wrapped in. When hidden, the width is considered `0` and therefore the width of the chart is set to `0`. I want to force redraw the chart when it is visible but I found nothing in the docs.

PS: The chart restores to its original size when I resize the window.

Comment: I found a workaround for now. I'm storing the new series data in a global variable and updating the chart whenever it is shown. It seems like a hack. I would appreciate a better solution

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

Comment: i knew it would work, because it work everytime i resize the browser dev console. unfortunately it doesnt work on my code. and still cant figure it out. using nuxt3 & composition api here

Answer (score 2):

I don't know weather it will be help you or not I have same issue using with apex chart some lables and title was missing but  when you resize the window it will automatically redraw the chart because apexchart have this property by default
chart: {
redrawOnWindowResize: true
}

I have try this this  put  chart render method inside timeout function and it works for me

```
setTimeout(() => {
            chart.render();
},2000)
```

In my case, it seems like chart rending before getting style of parent component

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My code block

```
    <div class="flex"
         id="chart">
    </div>
```

Initially I was using the following codes to manually resize the chart

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
},2000)
```

Because I was using flex container to contain the charts, the chart was rendered with smaller height and width and then it was snapping to the container.

To counter that, similar to answer by [Narayan Pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10075595/narayan-pandey), the following has worked for me so far by preventing the jump after initiation animation and this also solved the resizing issues for me.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    chart.render();
},10)
```